# How to upgrade Cordova 1.5.0 to Cordova 3.5.0 in an exsit project which was created 2 years ago?

Tags: ios, cordova

It's a project that was made two years ago and now I'm working with it. The question is that the version of the Cordova now 3.5.0 but this project was in 1.5.0. Can I run it in X-code 5.1 now? How can I upgrade it. Plz, I need help, for I'm a totally novice with iOS programs.

Next paragraph code error with that 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

```
#ifdef CORDOVA_FRAMEWORK
    #import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
#else
    #import "CDVViewController.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy way to upgrade from old versions of Cordova. You can try follow this guide: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrade.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS but you will have to upgrade step by step (i.e. from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 ...). But even when you do that, if you use some old plugins or API calls in your code you will have to rewrite them according to the new version's API.

I had a project using Cordova version 2.1 and I needed to upgrade it to 3.1 and in the end I was better off creating new project in 3.1 and then update plugins or completely rewrite them.

So to sum up, it all depends on complexity of your projects (how many platforms you support, if you communicate with native code, use plugins..). You can try following the update guide or just create a new project in 3.5. If your project is trivial, I suggest creating new 3.5 application and then copy old html, css, js... files to appropriate places in the new project according to 3.5's documentation.

Comment: Agreed with Matej P. - I have just upgraded from Phonegap 2.9 to Cordova 2.5 and found that creating NEW applications with the same names, and copying over the contents of the www (or asset) folders meant the app 'just worked'.  I had a few plugins so these had to be upgraded separately, but otherwise it was surprisingly pain free.

Comment: Thanks both of you, and I also checked the API of Cordova and found this guide:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_next_index.md.html#Next%20Steps Creatting new project will be fine.